# how to detect an Apk using sticky service? I don't have source code

Tags: android, service, sticky

In Android, the service can be a sticky service, and will be started automaticaly by system if it's killed.
But I don't have source code, how I know this, I don't want to run it on target devices, I just wanna know from scanning AndroidMenifest.xml or others.
is there any way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why? If you decompile the APK you should be able to find out. You can use apktool, dex2jar or a similar tool.

Comment: I know you mean returning START_STICKY on onStartCommand method, right?

Comment: Yes. Why do you care if a service is sticky in code you don't control?

Comment: I am going to check all the apks on the phone which use sticky returns.